# Is there a preprocessor macro to prevent others include a private header in C++?

Tags: c++, macros, c++17, c-preprocessor

I have a private.hpp header that should be used only for 2 classes, this header performs some operations that those classes use, however, other software engineers of my team started to use it in the same module, I had to fix those includes and add more methods to those classes. I want to know if there is a way to throw an error from the preprocessor or maybe linker to stop the usage of that header out of those 2 classes.

Comment: Use the combination #ifndef, #error in the private header and #define where including of the private header is allowed. This is the only way with weak restrictions.

Comment: Why not use the language instead of the preprocessor?  You could have your operations private in a class, then friend the classes allowed to use them.  It's probably better to abuse C++ like this than it is to abuse the preprocessor.  (Maybe one of your classes is already the ideal place to put them).

Comment: @HWalters is right : you should always use C++ features over preprocessor macros when possible. However, there are things that C++ itself cannot achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @S.M. mentionned, you can define a preprocessor variable in the files where you need your `secret.hpp` :

```
#define INTERNAL_OPERATIONS_ALLOWED // top of file
#include "secret.hpp"

// ...

#undef INTERNAL_OPERATIONS_ALLOWED // end of file
```

and add a condition on top of your `private.hpp` :

```
#if !defined(INTERNAL_OPERATIONS_ALLOWED)
    #error "DO NOT USE THIS HEADER"
#endif

// ...
```

or define your macros individually :

```
#ifdef INTERNAL_OPERATIONS_ALLOWED
    #define OPERATION(X) X
#else
    #error "DO NOT USE THIS OPERATION"
#endif
```

This will not prevent other developers to use your operations, but they will have to define the `INTERNAL_OPERATIONS_ALLOWED` on purpose, meaning that they are aware that they shouldn't.